# How to get date from database using stored procedure in JPA

Tags: oracle, date, jpa

I have a table with a column of date time. I am calling in my code behind a stored procedure for get all entities from my table. My problem is that i dont know how to get date column.

```
public List<Comment> getAllCommnents() {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("GET_ALL_COMMENTS")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

        if (!query.execute()) {
            log.error("Got a problem while executing query to find comment");
            return null;
        }

        List<Comment>listComments=new ArrayList<>();
        query.getResultList().forEach((line) -> {
            Object[] resultLine = (Object[]) line;
            Integer idComment = ((BigDecimal) resultLine[0]).intValueExact();
            String content = (String) resultLine[1];
            Date publicationDate = (Date) resultLine[2];
            String username = (String) resultLine[3];

            User user=new User(username);

            Comment comment=new Comment(idComment, user, publicationDate, content);
            listComments.add(comment);

    });

    return listComments;
    }
}
```

In json publicationDate appears like "1490862692302";
In database the date is: "30-MAR-17 11:31:32:30200000 AM:

Comment: `30-MAR-17 11:31:32:30200000 AM` is a timestamp not a date.

Comment: @APC, ok, but u can tell me how to do?

Comment: Your problem is not in the stored procedure, it's in the JSON marshaller. Could you share your Comment model, what are you using for marshalling JAX-B or something else?